# Sharing waste of washing machine with sink

Tags: plumbing, laundry

Is the plumbing below fine?

[image]

The part in red comes from behind a brick wall and the height on the exit pipe is at 50 cm, therefore, to avoid having to break the wall and redoing part of the plumbing I would like to share the waste links of the sink and washing machine.

Comment: Of course, use a [curved drain tee](http://images.lowes.com/product/converted/052063/052063444093lg.jpg) where the sink drain meets the washer drain.  That helps direct the water to reduce back flow.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't uncommon for washing Machines to drain *into* a utility sink, so I would expect this to be fine.

Comment: I know that, but in this case I'm doing the opposite, draining a sink into a washing machine pipe. I think that when the machine drain the sink might have a bit of backflow but not much. Other than that I don't see any thing that might go wrong, but I'm don't have much experience with plumbing to be sure. Also I don't need a trap for the sink now.

Comment: Point is, the drain should be adequate, there should be no backflow into themachine and minimal into the sink, and it will do no more harm than completely filling the sink befote draing it -- ie, none at all. Single trap _should_ be adequate, though a separate trap ,ight make recovery easier if you ever drop a ring or other small valuable into that sink.